# Search in different alphabets through mapped letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a simple search field where I can search only using English alphabet and numbers and my goal is to make the search to be able to search with English letters a different alphabet through mapped letters for example a = α, b = μπ, g = γ etc

I tried to make an object with all the letters for both languages and filter each letter before I use it to filter my data.

```
export function dataSearch(data, query) {
 if (!data || data.length === 0) return [];
 // if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(query)) detected English language  

 const lettersObj = [{a: 'α'}, {b: 'μπ'}, {g: 'γ'}]

 const newQuery = lettersObj.filter((l) => 
   Object.keys(l).join('').toLowerCase().match(query.toLowerCase())

 return data.filter((d) => {
 const dataString = Object.values(d).join('').toLowerCase();

return dataString.match(newQuery.toLowerCase());
 });
}
```

The expected results are to be able to search with en letters in both cases. If I have something typed in non en through the mapped letters I should have the same results.

Comment: What is the problem? What prevents you to implement what you need?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot return the results from the filtered data and also there are cases where I need to cover letters with tone for example ή which is same with simple η

Comment: Would it be an option to record the keycode from the keyboard (onKeyDown) and convert it into en letters?

Comment: I don't think it can work as I need to handle the letters with tones as well.

Comment: Can you give an example of your datasource?

Comment: This is the data source 
    id: 4,
    date: '30/08/2019',
    name: 'Χτένισμα',
    notes: null,
    pos: true,
    price: 12,

Comment: @PanosCool are you searching by name?

Comment: Not only, I'm searching the full dataset, name, notes etc

Comment: @PanosCool check my answer

Comment: @Kobe I'm sorry I forgot to mention one more thing, I need to exclude any Boolean, null or id and search through strings. I appreciate and I will check shortly your answer, thanks.

Comment: @PanosCool okay, changed my answer accordingly 

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one object, and convert the word letter by letter. Then, you can use can continue `Object.values`, but first check if the property is a `string`, and also use `some` and `includes` to check each if each of the properties contains that new word:

```js
const map = {a: 'α', b: 'μπ', g: 'γ'}
const data = [
  {id: 4, date: '30/08/2019', name: 'Χτένισμα', notes: null, pos: true, price: 12}
]

const search = (data, s) => {
  if (!data || data.length === 0) return [];
  
  const query = s.split('').map(l => map[l] || l).join('')

  return data.filter(d => Object.values(d).some(s => typeof s === "string" && s.includes(query)))
}

// Pass
console.log(search(data, 'a'))
console.log(search(data, '30/08'))

// Fail
console.log(search(data, 'null'))
console.log(search(data, '12'))
console.log(search(data, 'true'))
```